# What is the correct syntax for PATCH request in database query

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I am trying to place a update function. Everything seems to be except for the database query. Below are my code fragments. Help me fix this, please.

```
  const submitSalesUpdate = async () => {
    try {
      await axios
        .patch(
          `http://localhost:8081/update-sale/${rowToUpdate.fetchedRow}`,
          updateData
        )
        .then((res) => {
          window.location.reload(false);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("While updating sales record", err);
    }
    form.reset();
  };
```

Below is my API (if that is what its termed as). I can see all of the consoled values in server log.

```
app.patch("/update-sale/:fetchedRow", (req, res) => {
  console.log("initiating update");
  console.log(req.params.fetchedRow);
  console.log(req.body);

  const sql = //error is probably because of this line or the below line marked with comment
    "UPDATE sales SET (`product_name`, `price`, `quantity`, `total`, `seller`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id = 'rowId'"; 
  const values = [
    req.body.product,
    req.body.price,
    req.body.quantity,
    total,
    req.body.seller,
  ];
  db.query(sql, (err, data) => { //or because of this line
    if (err) {
      return res.json("error");
    }
    return res.json({ data });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your update statement follows the syntax for insert, not for update. See the answer to the duplicate question. The problem is with the sql syntax in both questions, the programming language of the application is irrelevant.

Comment: this may be the issue, can you help me with the correct update statement

Comment: Please check out the syntax suggested in the answer to the duplicate question. The sql syntax is the same, regardless of the application programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You're building the parameters array but you're not using it in your query. Perhaps you wanted to write `db.query(sql, values, (err, data) => {` instead?

You could verify that by printing the error to the console or sending it back as response, e.g. `console.log(err);` or `res.json(err);` (instead of text `"error"`). If I have to guess, it will say that the number of expected parameters does not match the number of actual parameters (which is 0)

Comment: no error, not in browser not in vs terminal

Comment: I am guessing that `mysql` client is trying to convert your callback to an array of values to be passed to your update statement, so the callback is not invoked. Have you tried adding the `values` right after `sql`, did it work?

Comment: yes i had the values right after but no error in logs and not updating as well

Comment: This helped:
"UPDATE sales SET product_name = ?, price = ?, quantity = ?, total = ?, seller = ? WHERE id = ?"